# How to test if there is a specific tagname in xml using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml

I want to check whether there is a specific tagname in an xml file, using javascript.
 pseudocode:

```
if (there_is_a_tag_name_called_<picture>)
{ variable=1;}
else
{variable=0;}
```

note: the `if( "tagname.length>0")` wont work....

how can I do it?

Comment: In what form do you have the XML? String, DOM, something else?

Comment: Look for an element with this tagname (by `getElementsByTagName` or `querySelector`), then check the result's length.

Comment: you can use simplexml, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8341138/using-php-simplexml-to-find-a-node-i-know-the-name-of-but-not-where-it-resides

Comment: and how are you getting this XML, is it a string or actual nodes etc. Not enough information here!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use this

```
if(node.getElementsByTagName("picture").length > 0){ 
variable=1;
 }
else
{variable=0;}
```

Comment: If there is not such a TagName as "picture" in the xml file, the above if statement will not work at all...

Comment: You mean it will not go to `else` part also ? Have you checked it ?

Answer (score -1):

I am unable to past html content,
Hence i am pasting my code as an image

[image]